# Не могу выровнять элементы (flexbox)

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

[Ссылка на картинки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kVsG.jpg)
Нужно позиционировать картинки как в макете:
[Макет](https://www.figma.com/file/4l5MEGfmM01SCA5cYsLLgr/ladesign-(Copy)?node-id=0%3A1) + фото на всякий случай как должно быть: [как должно быть](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chpau.jpg) и как у меня выходит: [как выходит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6tAm.jpg)

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content_img {
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-1.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-2.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-3.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-4.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-5.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-6.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-7.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-8.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-9.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
        <div class="content_img" id="hide_img">
            <img src="img/content/room-10.jpg" alt="Images">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: На гридах делайте. На чистых флексах такое не сделать.

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/mdEzbmv - так ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое нужно делать на гридах. Если нужно сделать на флексбокс, то единственный способ это оборачивать все в дополнительные контейнеры и выравнивать уже эти контейнеры

Comment: В таком случае лучше и правда на гридах ибо я сдохну пока с флексами буду морочиться. Можешь подсказать что хоть из гридов использовать, чтобы добиться такого результата?

Comment: Удобнее всего использовать grid-template-areas